# How to use Celery primitives with remote tasks?

Tags: python, django, celery, distributed-computing, django-celery

I would like to use celery's workflows such as group and chords on tasks located on another system. Currently using send_task() to execute these tasks, but now in need to group a multitude of these remote tasks.

Also interested to know if group has its own id field to refer to.

I've looked through Celery docs but can't seem to find anything to do with using primitives with remote tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Also couldn't find a way to do this from the documentation. I found a [GitHub thread](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1744) discussing something similar. Using signatures seems to work. However, not sure if it is the best solution:

```
app = Celery()
a = app.signature('proj.tasks.add', (2, 2))
b = app.signature('proj.tasks.add', (4, 4))

g = group([a, b], app=app)
result = g()
print(result.get())
```